# trigger the function on select option click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to trigger the function from select box.I have two option week1 and week2.If I change the select option week1 it will trigger the function.again If I click the same week1 option I want to call the same function.

#### [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r7zwq/14/)

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <select ng-model="select_value" ng-change="change()">
  <option value ="1" ng-click="change()">Week 1</option>
  <option value ="2">Week 2</option>
 </select>
  <div>counter = {{counter}}</div>
   </div>
   


 var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
 function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.counter = 1;
  $scope.change = function () {
   alert('change');
  };
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As `ng-change` is triggered only **when the value is changed**, it is not fired when you click 2 times the same value in your `<select>`.

You can use [`ng-click`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) instead:

```
<option ng-click="change()" value="1">Week 1</option>
```

### [Forked your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/fhva351n/)